# Sequence of group and Sequence of elements

Tags: html, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a scenario where there is sequence constraint on `<body>` to have a child `<a>` followed by `<b>`

```
 <body>
   <a />
   <b />
 </body
```

But, `<a>` and `<b>` are part of a group, so my XSD is like

```
 <xs:element name="body">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:group where <a> defined />
          <xs:group where <b> defined />
        </xs:sequence>
```

I am getting following data `<b>` followed by `<a>`,

```
 <body>
   <b />
   <a />
  </body
```

And the data is getting successfully validated, whereas I am expecting it to fail as it is not honoring the sequence. Is it like the validator does not recognize the Sequence of Groups (when elements are defined in groups) within `<xs:sequence>`.  Please suggest??

Also, when I defined these them as an element in a `<xs:sequence>` then the data is getting failed against the Schema, but the same is not failing when these elements are in groups and the groups are being referred in a `<xs:sequence>`.

Comment: The portion of the content model you show does have the meaning you describe.  But without the rest of that choice and the definitions of the groups, it's not possible to recreate the problem.  (Making a working version of the schema about this size that exhibits the difficulty would be a useful exercise in any case.)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and it seems to be working as you expect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="test" xmlns:test="test">

<xs:group name="a_group">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:group name="b_group">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="body">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:group ref="test:a_group" />
                <xs:group ref="test:b_group" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>                
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Following xml will validate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xsi:schemaLocation="test test.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="test">
    <a />
    <b />
</body>
```

Following won't

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xsi:schemaLocation="test test.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="test">
    <b />
    <a />
</body>
```

I tested it in Altova. What do you use for validation? 
I have some strange experience with some Java apps: when I have `choice` followed by `sequence` (without element between them), it works like if there only `choice` were declared (i.e. choice between `<a />` and `<b />`. (Similarly `sequence` containing `choice` works like only `sequence`.)
So if it were similar case, it is possible, that `minOccurs="0"` causes the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jirka. I removed the `minOccurs="0"` from Sequence, but still it is passing the data. Also, in my case, the groups are defines in seprate XSD which being referredin this XSD.

I am using **Oxygen** to validate the file. Also, i tried with ALTOVA, but `<b>` then `<a>` is getting passed. Should have failed...

Comment: Could you provide complete definition of both groups and also of `body` element definition?